# igraph: how to use add_edges when there are attributes?

Tags: python, igraph

What if I need to create a graph in `igraph` and add a bunch of edges, but the edges have associated attributes? It looks like `.add_edges` can only take a list of edges without attributes, so I've been adding them one by one with `.add_edge`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign the attributes later; e.g.:

```
graph.es["weight"] = range(g.ecount())
```

This will assign weights to all the edges at once. If you want to assign attributes to only a subset of the edges, index or slice the edge sequence (`g.es`) in however you want:

```
graph.es[10:20]["weight"] = range(10)
```

Comment: Is there a way to add multiple attributes at once?  My data is a dictionary of dictionaries; the outer dictionary is keyed by edges, the inner dictionary are attribute/value pairs: 

`{(0,1): {'weight':5,'age':3} ...}`

RIght now I'm doing something like

`graph.es['weight'] = [x['weight'] for x in edge_dict]
graph.es['age'] = [x['age'] for x in edge_dict]`

which works fine, I'm just curious if I'm missing something.

Comment: You are doing it just fine, there is no better way of doing it as far as I know.

Answer (score 17):

```
graph.add_edge('A','B',weight = 20)
```

Here A and B are names of nodes

Comment: Keep in mind that `graph.add_edge` calls the vertex id indexer every time. This results in very slow behavior when you're adding a lot (> few hundred) vertices to a graph at once. `graph.add_edges` is good for situations where you want to add vertices in bulk.